# How to add use a pointer to member value as a template parameter by type (not value)

Tags: c++, member-pointers

My situation:

I frequently need to have a vector of structures where one field can be thought of as a Key or ID, and rather than store it expensively in a map (memory usage is very important in this app) I want to store it in a flat vector but present a map-like interface for finding elements by key.

My first solution to this problem:

```
template <class T, class Key, class KeyFn>
class TKeyedVector : public std::vector<T>
{
public:

    const_iterator      find(const Key& key) const {return std::find_if(begin(), end(), [&](const T& entry) {return keyFn(entry)==key; }); }

    KeyFn keyFn;
};

struct KeyedDataEntry
{
  std::string       key;
  int               value;

  struct KeyExtractor {
    const std::string& operator()(const KeyedDataEntry& e) const {return e.key; };
  };
};

using KeyedDataArray = TKeyedVector<KeyedDataEntry, std::string, KeyedDataEntry::KeyExtractor>;
```

Now this all works, but I would like to be able to remove the need for the `KeyExtractor` type by using the pointer to the member variable embedded into the type:

```
template <class T, class Key, Key T::* keyFn>
class TKeyedVector : public std::vector<T>
{
public:
        const_iterator      find(const Key& key) const {return std::find_if(begin(), end(), [&](const T& entry) {return keyFn(entry)==key; }); }
};

using KeyedDataArray = TKeyedVector<KeyedDataEntry, std::string, &KeyedDataEntry::key>;
```

However I can't get this to work. I've been looking at the implementation of `std::mem_fn` for clues, but I can't work out how to do it.  The error I get with is something like:

```
 warning C4353: nonstandard extension used: constant 0 as function expression.  Use '__noop' function intrinsic instead
```

Any clues?

EDIT: sample version at http://ideone.com/Qu6TEy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the start of a working solution. You don't need a special extractor object.

Note that I have encapsulated the vector. In time, you'll regret not doing this.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <class T, class Key, const Key& (T::*Extractor)() const>
class TKeyedVector
{
    using storage = std::vector<T>;
    using const_iterator = typename storage::const_iterator;
public:

    decltype(auto) begin() const
    {
        return storage_.begin();
    }

    decltype(auto) end() const
    {
        return storage_.end();
    }

    const_iterator find(const Key& key) const
    {
        return std::find_if(begin(),
                            end(),
                            [&](const T& entry)
        {
            return entry.*Extractor() == key;
        });
    }

    storage storage_;
};

struct KeyedDataEntry
{
    std::string       key;
    int               value;

    const std::string& get_key() const { return key; }

};

int main()
{
    TKeyedVector<KeyedDataEntry, std::string, &KeyedDataEntry::get_key> mymap;

}
```

But there is a problem with this idea of yours.

In order for this structure to be a map, the keys must be immutable. This argues for only returning immutable objects. This then argues immediately for simply using an `unordered_set` or `set`.

If you're going to return references to mutable objects in the underlying vector, then you may as well simply use `std::find_if` with a predicate to find them.

Comment: Thanks - this got me to to the solution I needed.  The key was the syntax for the definition of the Extractor in the template and then how the Extractor is dereferenced in the `find()` function.  In the case I have, immutability of keys isn't a problem because it doesn't have to function totally like a map - I just want to be able to find items by an ID-like field.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to member requires the pointer to member call syntax. `(entry.*keyFn)()`

C++17 will come with a standard `std::invoke` function to make writing such templates a bit less tiresome (it will work for all callable objects). But in the meanwhile, this is how you need to do this.

Comment: I've tried adapting to that syntax, but no luck (see ideone link above). Error is: 
`prog.cpp:15:29: error: no match for call to '(const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}) ()'
        return (entry.*keyFn)()==key; `

Comment: @the_mandrill you define the return type of the member as `std::string` yet pass a member that returns `const std::string&`. That's unrelated to the question at hand. You need to define a traits class to adjust the return type.